# Django template table with missing data for some columns

Tags: python, django, templates

Okay, I give up. I searched through and through and lost something that looked like an answer, so I have to ask.

Say, data for a regional power grid and each power plant has a production plan for a day, all of them go as list of dicts with a plan for every hour. Data also include a power consumption forecast, which naturally only has data for hours in the future.

```
[
 {'station_id':'Grid','plan_code':1000,'plan':{1:300,2:500,3:250,...,23:519,24:200}}
 {'station_id':'Plant1','plan_code':1001,'plan':{1:100,2:224,3:150,...,23:239,24:100}}
 {'station_id':'Plant2','plan_code':724,'plan':{1:200,2:226,3:100,...,23:240,24:100}} #every hour contains value
 {'station_id':'Consumption','plan_code':2003,'plan':{21:1600,22:1710,23:1250,24:1100}} #only few hours have data
]
```

What I'm trying to generate with Django template is a table of power grid production, consumption and balance values:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <th>Plan for</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            ...
            <th>22</th>
            <th>23</th>
            <th>24</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for plan in plans %}
        <tr style="font-size: small">
            <td>{{ plan.station_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ plan.plan_code }}</td>
            {% for hour,val in plan.plan %}
               <td>{{ val }}</td>
            {%endfor%}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The questions are:

1. How dow I determine order in which plans are displayed?
2. How do I fill a row with consumption plan with empty cells if no value is provided for that hour?

Please, help a beginner here.

Comment: What order are you trying to display them in? And can you post your views.py and models.py as well?

Answer (score 0):

Figured that out.

If you have missing cells in your table you need to add and you aren't using pandas yet, you can complete dictionary with keys with `None` values.

```
    hours = range(1,25)

    for ob in a:
        for plan in a[ob]['plans']:
            if len(a[ob]['plans'][plan]) < 24:
                for h in hours:
                   a[ob]['plans'][plan][h] = a[ob]['plans'][plan].get(h)
                a[ob]['plans'][plan] = dict(sorted( a[ob]['plans'][plan].items()))
```